How to provide different `runConfig` inside `apphosting.yaml` for different firebase project deployments?
I was trying out the newly unveiled Firebase App Hosting (public preview) with NextJs app and it needs an apphosting.yaml file for server configuration. I have 2 environments namely 'production' and 'staging' and 2 firebase projects for them. I can switch between those projects locally using firebase use production and I want to deploy my app with different run configurations for both of these. I have set up the Github connection for both, using develop branch for staging project and main branch for production project. Is there a way to configure different run configurations for the same?
I need for different configurations is genuine, especially for the minInstance configuration:
Production:
runConfig:
  # Number of containers to always keep alive (default 0)
  minInstances: 1

Staging:
runConfig:
  # Number of containers to always keep alive (default 0)
  minInstances: 0

This is important so that I don't incur cost for staging environment keeping 1 instance always alive. Is there a way that I can achieve this?

We have a super easy way to do this on the roadmap, but the best way to do this for now is to have a production branch with minInstances: 1 that you merge development into and each backend has a different target branch.

Yes, for now I am keeping an extra commit in main branch with minInstances: 1, is there any timeline for when this will be implemented? Thanks for the answer.

I don’t want to commit to timelines and have it slip, but I’ve proposed it for our immediate fast follow roadmap.
